# Hide WooCommerce Subscriptions Cancel Button 2 Days Before Subscription Renewal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to hide the cancel subscription button within the subscription details in 'My Account', before the last 2 days of subscription renewal.

For example, the subscription renewal date of 30 Oct 2022 and the cancel button should hide on 28 Oct 2022, however, the Cancel button still shows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
function jk_remove_cancel_button( $actions, $subscription_id ) {

    // Gets the subscription object on subscription id
    $subscription = new WC_Subscription( $subscription_id );
  
    $next_payment_date = $subscription->get_date( 'next_payment', 'site' );

    $nt = strtotime($next_payment_date);
    $local_time  = current_datetime();
    $ct = $local_time->getTimestamp() + $local_time->getOffset();
  
    // Get the difference in date
    $diff = $ct - $nt;
    $final = abs(round($diff / 86400));
    // Change the number (days) according to your choice
    if ($final <= "2") {
        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
    }
  
    // Return the actions
    return $actions;
} add_filter( 'wcs_view_subscription_actions', 'jk_remove_cancel_button', 100, 2);
```

This code will hide cancel subscription button before 2 days of subscription renewal.

Tested Perfectly.